# How do I turn my optibay hard drive into a slave storage?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, macos

I have a new SSD and my old hard drive installed in my optibay. My old hard drive currently has a Mac OS system on it, and I want to just wipe it so I can use it for storing my videos, and pictures. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want to use Disk Utility to erase the HDD or have you another plan in mind?

Answer (score 2):

Can you boot into the laptop from the SSD OS while both drives are in your laptop?

If so, just open disk utility, select your old HDD drive, and select the erase tab.

From there you can reformat your hard drive.

Answer (score 2):

Best would be to re-install a clean system on the SSD althought you could user "**Carbon Copy Cloner**" to do so simply unticking your user folder. Then to cross link the system on the SSD and your data on the PHD (plates) you can do so several ways :

- If you want to access all your data from the old hard disk simply after a first login and a new user folder create automatically after the login you may go in "**System Preferences"** > "**Users and Groups**" right click your user and point the user "**Home directory**" towards your user folder inside the PHD.
- Another way would be to create an alias or better symbolic link to the directory this could be achieve from the terminal from the recovery partition or via single user (**cmd** - **S**) while starting and then typing (QWERTY keyboard dash is 2 keys left from backspace and slash is the key next to right shift) :

  mount -uw /

Then create the link :

```
ln -s /Volumes/*SSD*/Users /Volumes/*PHD*/Users
```

- One last way is simply to replace heavy folders by aliases or symlink pointing on the appropriate folder on your PHD. Eg **ln -s ~/Music /Volumes/*PHD*/Music** and put your iTunes folder and whatever stuff related to audio inside…

I think the third solution is the best because you preserve configuration and commonly used files on the SSD…

PS : I would discourage to use non-Apple stuff to manage Fusion drive, we are talking about datas. You don't want to make an update that would create problems… Thus manually managing what to put on the SSD is the most secure / viable / reasonnable solution.

NB : The main difference between hardlinks and symbolic link is that you may delete the **files** pointed by a symbolic link (-s option of the link command) but not by a hardlink. Hardlink only works with files.

Comment: I'd be inclined to agree with manually managing the data yourself, instead of using non-apple stuff. saves the chances of a hard drive failure

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered building your own Fusion drive using the SSD/HDD as a single combined drive to get the best of both worlds? Here is an example - http://jollyjinx.tumblr.com/post/34638496292/fusion-drive-on-older-macs-yes-since-apple-has.

Answer (score 0):

I have a point to add to this. As I understand you have left the HDD where it was, next to the battery and have replaced your optical drive with a SSD inside a carrier (similar to the one at hardwrk.com). This configuration is a waste because you have given your HDD the faster SATA connection on the MLB and your SSD the slower one.
Swap these drives so that the SATAII(I) is going to the SSD and your HDD gets the P/SATA connection.

What might be fun, if you are running 10.8.3 or newer is setting them up as a fusion drive so that you get the speed of flash both the capacity of both drives added together. Be aware though that you should always keep an active backup and I only set these up for people if they have a fully functioning Time Machine setup. (http://jollyjinx.tumblr.com/post/34638496292/fusion-drive-on-older-macs-yes-since-apple-has)